# How to calculate a part of a spectrum from another part of it?

Tags: radio-astronomy, radio, black-body

I have some radio data (flux) in 1.4 GHZ and also distance data. I calculated the luminosity for this frequency. Here, i want to use power-law and/or blackbody relation to calculate possible luminosity values of the same sample at a 5GHZ.

I found the way: $$L_R=v*L_v= 5 GHz*L_5 = (5 GHz)*4*\pi*D^2*F_5$$

Here $$L_R$$ is luminosity at the observed frenquency. $$L_5,F_5$$ are the luminosity and flux density at 5GHz.

Btw, forgot to multiply the luminosity with 1.4GHZ while calculating  $$L_{1.4}$$ or (whatever you say) $$L_v, L_R$$

I suggest that the only thing that i need to do is multiplying the luminosity value with 5GHZ. Or need to divide by 5GHZ? Im confused here.

Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: Look at the units of your variables

Comment: What planetmaker is (for some reason only) hinting at is the idea of using [dimensional analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional_analysis). If you forget the numbers and just put the correct units in each place of an equation, it should also balance/agree. For example if we have to choose between F=ma and F=m/a the units give us the answer. (kg m / s^2) = (kg) x (m/s^2). Check the units for luminosity you are supposed to use (maybe watts, maybe unitless ratio to L☉) and the units for flux density. What happens when you work it through using dimensional analysis?

Comment: Okay i got the point. Actually i did this before. How ever my flux is in jansky and distance in cm, and the luminosity unit that i want is erg s^-1. So, i'm confused about where to put that Hz thing.